# How to check if the webView has loaded the next page in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

When the application is opened a webView opens say "www.google.com". If the user types in some query and presses Search(in the WebView itself, not an Android button)  the next page loads. Now my need is to know if the webView has loaded the next page that is the search results for the query.

Is there any built-in method to check that?

**EDIT 1**

Implementing the method of Asuthosh Panda and Chintan Soni. It still doesn't work. This is implemented in a fragment. Does that affect the code in any way?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    String url;
    //String urrrl=null;
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_net_con, container, false);
    myWebView = (WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView21);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    url=myWebView.getUrl().toString();
    Log.d("My app msg","I am here");
    Log.d("URL ",url);
    if(url.contains("q=")){
        System.exit(1);
    }
    activityCommander.setwebs(myWebView.getUrl());

    return view;    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a callback with `WebViewClient` as below:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if you write this in Fragment or Activity. Also, I can see you haven't overridden the method `onPageFinished()`

Answer (score 3):

**I don't know what are you asking really**

**So, I am sharing my Simple Browser Project code**

Hoping it will Help you

**First,you need to define a WebView Client Class**

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient{
@Override

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    view.loadUrl(url);

    return true;
 }
}
```

**Secondly edit Activity main like this**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


public void sendGo(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,GoActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
 }

}
```

**Thirdly GGoActivity like this**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class GoActivity extends Activity {

WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_go);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_go);

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 }
}
```

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 1):

1. For the WebView, you can get the URL of the page you are currently
   in when the page has finished loading. See the answer posted by @Chintan Soni
2. For every query you search, Google's URL that uses Get method for
   sending the search query would look something like this -

   > https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=psUGWeHZKe3I8Af2rL7YAg#q=android

   where **q** is the key for the query (your searched String). Here I searched for 'android'.

   So if your URL contains "q=", it means that you have searched
   something and are on the the search results page.

So your code should be something like -

```
if(url.contains("q=")){
 // its the search page and not the initial Google home page
}
```